# What pattern of ZMQ must be used for the following scenario?

Tags: python, zeromq

I have started learning ZMQ (Python) very recently. I must admit, I am finding it hard to understand **`PUSH/PULL`** and **`DEALER/ROUTER`** patterns.

My problem statement is the following:

1. **`N`** number of Client's (e.g. 100) will send request (query for some data,  access a resource, etc) at 10:00:00 (hr:min:sec) AM
2. Server must process all the `N` Request at 10:00:00 AM.
3. Assume that a request takes 30 Seconds to complete, all the client's (100) must receive the response at 10:00:30 AM
4. What pattern of ZMQ should I use ?

> I understood that `REQ/REP` is synchronous and I can't use that pattern to solve the particular problem. (Server can process only one request at a time)

Please help me with a sample program/link to develop a client/server application using ZMQ. ( Server must at least process 100 requests at a time)

**If the number of request's increases next day, will I be able to scale using ZMQ?
If yes, how?**

Answer (score 4):

You have **`N`** clients and 1 server.
The server will not be able to complete the `N` requests **simultaneously**.
Obviously, the server can start processing the `N` requests at 10:00:00 AM sharp using a crontab or other scheduling mechanism.

The appropriate ZMQ pattern seems to be **`PUSH/PULL`**. See http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all

and navigate to `Figure 6 - Fair Queuing.`

To answer your scaling question: you could see the server as a single entry point for the requests, with a number (`>= N`) of parallel workers behind the server. This architecture is shown in `Figure 20 - Multithreaded Server`.

That architecture would theoretically solve the concurrency problem, but with a few important remarks:

1. Real parallel execution is only available if you have a separate CPU core for each worker (note: they may be spread across several machines using `tcp://` addresses). If you have `< N` cores available, you end up in a situation where you make the work parallel and the OS makes it sequential again.
2. If the execution time on the worker is I/O bound (i.e. database queries, filesystem access etc.), cut your graph up in smaller nodes and make only the CPU bound tasks parallel.
3. A single server, even if it only fowards requests to a pool of workers, is a scalability limit. At one point in your design you will need to make choices related to the [CAP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem).

Comment: Sorry to note @Freek, **`ZeroMQ`** is a very helpful tool-box, a trivial `PUSH/PULL` primitive behaviour pattern does not solve the scheme. As noted above, the queueing of incoming requests is not the corner-stone of the design.

Comment: The PUSH/PULL pattern assumes a single server (there was mention of N clients and 1 server in the original post). I agree with you that that architecture cannot deliver the concurrency. I edited the answer to go into the concurrency and scalability concerns ('Multithreaded server' and everythin below).

Comment: does that mean even if i use the DEALER/ROUTER pattern in a machine with single core, it is equivalent to the REQ/REP pattern ?

Comment: @deepak: not completely. In REQ/REP the requests will be processed 1 by 1. Request `i+1` is only started as soon as `i` is returned to the client. In ROUTER/DEALER with worker pool, multiple requests will be on the worker pool at the same time. But the scheduler in the OS will have to switch between the workers; effectively there's only one task computing at any time. For I/O bound tasks this is still a speedup, though it's not the best way to go.

Comment: Assume that the Server has 'N' worker processes running, each worker process connects to a ZMQ REQ Socket, when ever a socket.send () request is made, the logic to compute the reply is executed in any of the found nodes the cluster (the cluster has 'N' Nodes). Do you think this will solve the problem ?.  Do you think it is ideal to use the REQ/REP pattern in this case. Because my main intention is to delegate the task to the node in the cluster.

Comment: So we work with `N` clients. Each has a `REQ` socket. There is 1 server which has a `ROUTER` socket and a `DEALER` socket (example from figure 20 in the ZeroMQ guide). There are `N` workers, each with a `REP` socket; all these workers connect to the `DEALER` (see code: http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:mtserver). Then every `send()` on a client will be automatically routed to an available worker.

Comment: Assuming that the workers are mainly I/O bound (like querying external data sources), this will make the work parallel. With the drawback that a large threadpool is not the most efficient way to run parallel jobs. If the work is more CPU bound, the performance won't go up on a single core machine.

Comment: @FreekWiekmeijer DEALER/ROUTER looks like an ideal option for the problem i was trying to address using zmq, how many request's can the ROUTER socket queue ?

Comment: Only limited by the heap size, or may be limited in a socket option.

Answer (score 3):

### Scaleability first:

Yes, **`ZeroMQ`** is a power-tool for this. Without going to low-level details, your scenario has more problems with server-side process management, than with any `ZeroMQ`-related parts.

Once more power is needed, ZeroMQ can increase it's processing powers just by adding appropriate resources on the processing side of the pattern and your client-side ( requestors' ) code does not have to change a SLOC.

---

### Hard Real-time constraints:

If your `1-2-3` schematic's timing permits on the server side ( and we speak about milliseconds and microseconds inaccuracy to meet the 30 seconds hard-real-time parallelism, which goes head straight against wall in 100+ processing tasks for 4-core / 8-core / MPPA-manycore processor unit ),
 your code
may proceed with
a scaleable **Load-balancing Message Broker** [[Figure 32]](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#A-Load-Balancing-Message-Broker), which can solve **in a concurrent manner** the `1-2-3` scheme.

If striving to meet 10:00:30:000.000000 millisecond barrier, your processing side has to go distributed -- i.e. more real-hosts for the **`[worker]`** processes ( not any VMs in any kind of "on-demand" cloud-provisioning fiction ).
One single server simply cannot make **`N*30[sec]`** in less than `30[sec]` for `N > 2` ( do not forget the costs of concurrent scheduling and message-processing-flow overheads ).

---

### Real-world System Architecture must contain more "wires":

If your code strives to go production, not just an academia example, there will have to be more work to be done, to provide surviveability measures for real-world production environments.

A good read for realistic designs with ZeroMQ is Pieter HINTJEN's book **"Code Connected, Vol.1"** ( check my posts on ZeroMQ to find the pdf-link ).

Plus another good read comes from Martin SUSTRIK, the co-father of ZeroMQ, on [low-level truths about the ZeroMQ implementation details & scale-ability](http://nanomsg.org/documentation-zeromq.html)

---

<sub>**Epilogue:** `REQ/REP` primitive behaviour communication pattern is dangerous in real-world as it can self-deadlock the communication processes pair in case a transport ( for whatever reason ) has lost a packet and the "pendulum"-style message delivery gets incomplete and locked forever.</sub>

Comment: Currently, I am using uWSGI as the app server, the idea is to have 'N' uWSGI worker process (will connect to a REP socket and wait for the reply) and 'K' ZMQ REP sockets (which will do all the processing work).  Which is the ideal ZMQ pattern to use, so that the workers don't take a long time to respond. Is it ideal to have N == K. please suggest. Note uWSGI also allows to specify the number of threads.